# how to write dll file to access pdf

Tags: c#

Hi i'm new programming and i have written few application to access pdf content by using some dll files, but now my question is how can we write our own dll to access the pdf files. I know it's a big process but i'm very much interested to learn about this. any one please help me.

Comment: Perhaps you should explain why you don't want to use 3rd party DLLs - it may help people answer your question more accurately.

Answer (score 5):

You can start by reading the [PDF specification](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf) (warning 32MB behind this link) in order to understand how the PDF file format is implemented. This is necessary if you want to be able to parse it and extract the information you are interested in.

In the meantime (as this reading might occupy you during a certain amount of time) if you have pressing project deadlines you probably want to use an existing library such as [iTextSharp](http://itextpdf.com/).

Answer (score 1):

> I know it's a big process but i'm very much interested to learn about this.

That's true. I'd like to suggest to study some open source APIs ([iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/files/)) and [PDF SDK](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/library.html).